# Merging values of two columns of dataframe with different dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas `dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"pos": [1, 2, 3], "chain": ["A", "B", "C"]})
```

Giving:

```
  chain  pos
0     A    1
1     B    2
2     C    3
```

and `df.types`:

```
chain    object
pos       int64
dtype: object
```

I'm looking for a way to merge Series `df["chain"]` and `df["pos"]` to have the following:

```
   chain+pos
0     A1
1     B2
2     C3
```

and `df.dtypes`:

```
chain+pos    object
dtype: object
```

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [34]: df['chain'] += df.pop('pos').astype(str)

In [35]: df
Out[35]:
  chain
0    A1
1    B2
2    C3
```

renaming column:

```
In [37]: df = df.rename(columns={'chain':'chain+pos'})

In [38]: df
Out[38]:
  chain+pos
0        A1
1        B2
2        C3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df.astype(str).sum(1)
Out[489]: 
0    A1
1    B2
2    C3
dtype: object
```

Comment: @MaxU old fashion :-)

Answer (score 3):

The solution by MaxU works very well. Otherwise you can use the following also

```
df["chain+pos"] = df['chain'] + df['pos'].map(str)
```

After this, you have to drop df['chain'] and df['pos'] to attain the desired result.

----------------- Edit

As @MaxU pointed out in his comment below, here is a concise way of achieving the desired result -

```
df['chain+pos'] = df.pop('chain') + df.pop('pos').map(str)
```

Comment: actually it's a good idea we can do everything in one command: `df['chain+pos'] = df.pop('chain') + df.pop('pos').map(str)` +1

Comment: Super clever. I will not edit my answer. Credit must go to you :)

Comment: maybe you could write an **edit** to your answer at the bottom adding that line of code giving the proper credit to @MaxU

Comment: Actually `.map(str)` has value when the integer column has `NaN` values. In that case I believe the output of `.astype(str)` would be `1.0`, `2.0`, etc. With `.map(str)` you can add a format like `%.0f` to control this.